# Angular Dart, material-input outline

Tags: dart, material-design, angular-dart

how can i do a material input with outline border like the image? If possible i would like to add floatingLabel too. [Material input outiline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGmSC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please, have a look to the documentation provided [here](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_input)

Floating label is an option.
For outline, you have to custom the component styles. Don't hesitate to have a look into the examples source code on [github](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/tree/master/examples/material_input_example)

Comment: how can i custom the component styles? Do you have some example ?